# Initialize ref. field with ref. parameter: Is a copy made?

Tags: c++

I am wondering if a copy is made in the following situation, or if both references will point to the same object. Consider an class with a single const ref field which is initialized from const ref parameter:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(const vector<double>& the_doubles) : my_doubles(the_doubles) {}
 private:
  const vector<double>& my_doubles;
}
```

So, will my_doubles point to the same vector that was passed in to the constructor, or will a copy be created?

Comment: When passing  a *const* reference to the constructor, take great care not to pass a temporary! Otherwise your stored reference will immediately be invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference merely introduces an alias for an existing name (or, sometimes, value). Consider:

```
int a = 42;
int& b = a;
```

`b` is now an alias for `a`. If we furthermore write

```
int& c = b;
```

then `c` is an alias for `b` and hence in turn for `a`.

The same applies in your situation: no copy is ever made.

Comment: If you say `int& c = b;` then `c` is *immediately* an alias for `a`.

Answer (score 2):

there is no copy made, both will point to the same obj

Answer (score 1):

It will refer ("point") to the same vector that was passed in the constructor.

Otherwise reference members would be pretty useless!

Comment: Yeah, it occurred to me that it might be pointless otherwise!

Comment: In this particular case the reference member may indeed be useless (bound to a temporary, remaining valid only in the constructor). Use only with extreme care (an internal class whose usage is under your control)?

Comment: Have you misread the question? There is no temporary that I can see - the constructor is passed a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing by reference. Since it is required to be `const` there will only be read access to the variables in the vector. Since it is *pass by reference* no copy will be made. `my_doubles` will be a `const` reference to whatever `vector` was passed into your constructor.